# Matplotlib Boolean Plot Rectangle Fill

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a boolean data plot with Matplotlib & Python. I have several boolean channels and I would like to fill with a colour if the channel is = 1 (or True)

I have found 
[this C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748455/chart-displaying-boolean-flags-in-a-time-plot-as-filled-rectangles-instead-of?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which shows pretty much what I want in the bottom plot of 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stYLs.png).

My current idea is to use multiple subplots with a shared x-axis and use `fill_between` to fill the times when my channel is =1.

Before I press ahead with coding this, I wondered if there is already something in Matplotlib that would make this easier? I'd like to not have to worry about y values to control heights, but rather treat it more like a  horizontal bar plot , except that my x axis is time series and my bar has gaps in it.

Comment: The matplotlib gallery is always worth trawling for ideas https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html.  Click on any image to see the code that produced it.  In particular, this looks relevant: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/span_regions.html

Comment: This will work similarly to [fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) since fill between has where as a boolean argument. Still useful to have another way to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used matplotlib [`ax.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines) to solve this.

I also used a function to find the start and end idx of the true values in the array. I got this from another post on SO, but I can't find it now!

```
import numpy as np

def findones(a):
    isone = np.concatenate(([0], a, [0]))
    absdiff = np.abs(np.diff(isone))
    ranges = np.where(absdiff == 1)[0].reshape(-1, 2)
    return np.clip(ranges, 0, len(a) - 1)

def plotbooleans(ax, dictofbool):
    ax.set_ylim([-1, len(dictofbool)])
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(dictofbool.keys())))
    ax.set_yticklabels(dictofbool.keys())

    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(dictofbool.items()):
        indexes = findones(value)
        for idx in indexes:
            if idx[0] == idx[1]:
                idx[1] = idx[1]+1
            ax.hlines(y=i, xmin=idx[0], xmax=idx[1], linewidth=10, colors='r')
return ax
```

Test code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
testarray = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
testbool = {}
for i in range(0, 5):
    testbool['bool_{}'.format(i)] = testarray
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plotbooleans(ax, testbool)
plt.grid()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.show()
```

The output should look like this:
[image: boolean plot]