# Plotting of temporal graphs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, timeline

I have a 2d numpy array which gives the presence of a particular object in that frame so I have numpy array of shape (5829,7), where we have detected 7 tools (0 or 1) in 5829 frames. The array will look like this-

[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

We need to plot all these 7 objects presence in a single graph like shown in picture-

[This is sample plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Df09.png)

Here a,b...,f are different objects on the Y axis and X-axis contains the count of frames (shown in minutes actually 1 fps).

I have no idea how to plot these.
Anyone who plotted such a graph?

Comment: Welcome to sof. Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634844/matplotlib-boolean-plot-rectangle-fill